# How to get bootstrap button to fit text that is wrapped?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap 4 and have buttons that have text that is longer than the width:

```
<table><tr><td style="width:100px">
<button class="btn btn-default" style="white-space:normal">Some Text here I have</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Some Text here I have</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Some Text here I have</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Some Text here I have</button>
</td></tr></table>
```

I tried adding 'white-space:normal' as shown above, but the text gets cut off and the buttons stay the same height, cutting off text that is wrapped. How do I make it so that the button displays with the correct height and either: 1) Shrink Text to fit Button or 2) Size button big enough to show all text when wrapped?

Comment: Seems somewhat "impossible" (bar extreme effort) unless you can just let the table cell size as appropriate by removing that 100px width? I assume you cannot for some reason? Then you'll just have to shorten the text or lower the font size/padding on the button?

Comment: hi, I guess you have to shrink the text size because your cell is only 100px.. that's so small btw.. i'm not wondering why you get such behaviour.. use font size..

Comment: i would use label label-default to make the text size smaller and associate a click event... it would look exactly like buttons

Comment: I know dynamic shrinking of text may be difficult, but am okay with it wrapping and making the button taller.

Comment: I'm not seeing the text cutoff, it resizes the button beyond 100px, and with `white-space: normal` it wraps.

Comment: I see the text wrap, but the button background is only colored for the unwrapped parts.It's like the text sticks out of the button after wrap.